# Дефект при выборе отслеживаемого знака

Tags: дефект

Когда пишу `участ` в поиске (и есть несколько подходящих знаков), выдаётся всё нормально:
[image: Всё нормально]
Но когда остаётся один подходящий значок (я набрал `участк`), всё становится ужасно:
[image: Всё ужасно]

Надписи лезут друг на друга, вылезают из областей, а огромное место пустует. Не лучше ли просто расширить поле для значка?

Comment: [Известная история](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367433/339911)